# Excel 2016 restart itself when I try recording a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I wanted to make a **Macro** in **Excel 2016 (under Win 10)**. I chose the **"Record Macro"** button. After opening the floating window and making a name for the macro, I click on the **"OK"** button. After that, the Excel goes to hang mode for two, three seconds and then the Excel restart itself.
On the other hand, the button **"Use Relative Reference"** in Developer menu does not work and it's highlight always.

Shortly, I can not make a Macro in Excel 2016 under Win 10, any advice is appreciated. Thanks Guys ...

Comment: Try Disabling Hardware Acceleration in Advanced Options. File-->Options-->Advanced-->Display and Check Disable hardware graphics acceleration.

Comment: @pat2015
Thank you for your advise I done but the problem is still there.

Comment: Try to Repair Office installation and see if it fixes anything.

Comment: @pat2015 ... thank you my friend,  I did it (repairing the office) but the issue is still yet.

Comment: Might not be so relevant but just also try completely disabling any third party antivirus software if installed including its service in control panel. Are you recording a macro on a blank worksheet or on a sheet that's already saved as .xlsm?

Comment: @pat2015 ... Actually No. I can not record any Macro in a new worksheet or saved as .xlsm !! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue! ... I did a click on the **"Reference ..."** in VBA Developer in Excel and I get this message: **Unrecognised Project Language** then I went to the **Regional Setting** and I cleaned up (uncheck) the Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 ... Now the VBA work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case if I entered record macro or even the macro area the excel file restarted every time without accessing the macro areas.
I found the following worked for me. Went to xlstart folder and deleted the personal.xlsb file Opened a new file and saved as Personal.xlsb. Everything worked again but of course i lost all the existing macros that were in the original file. Thankfully I had copy pasted these to a word file.
Mike